# Edit page's "Restore the backup" link does nothing

Tags: pages, admin, backup

Every now and then WP logs me out and a pop-up requires me to log back in. After this happens and I am back in, I try to save some changes to a page I'm working on, but there is an error like "Are you sure you want to do that?"

I return to the page and there is an admin notice:

> The backup of this post in your browser is different from the version
>   below. [Restore the backup.](http://#)

I click the link and the message is

> Post restored successfully. [Undo](http://#).

However I can't see any changes. The editor view doesn't change or refresh. In fact, if I try to leave the page, I'm warned about navigating away. If I do so anyway, the same admin notice appears when I return/refresh. If I instead click *update*, then the last version is saved. I've been searching unsuccessfully, **how can I actually restore the 'local storage' backup?**

(WP 4.4.1, Avada theme)

Comment: Have you tried with a default theme? Avada is a hell of a complex beast (that by the way does things in a theme that plugins should be doing) and you better be sure that this really is a WP issue and not an Avada one.

Comment: I figured it out. It might very well be Avada! The notice is unhelpful and misleading, so I was stuck for a while.

Answer (score 1):

This notice isn't helpful. On the same page there is something like:

> Revisions: 29 [Browse](http://#)

After you have clicked [Restore the backup](http://#), you can click on [Browse](http://#). This will take you to the revisions of the page. If you move the slider all the way to the right, it will display an `[Autosave]` revision. You can click [Restore This Revision](http://#) to recover the autosave version.

*Note:* I can't confirm nor deny this, but it could be an Avada theme issue.

Comment: You can [edit] questions and answers.